# How to reformatted array

Tags: php

I have an array with indexes like

```
$array = array(
    "first_name" => "test",
    "last_name" => "testsurename"
);
```

I need to convert it to:

```
$array = array(
    "0" => array("first_name" => "test"),
    "1" => array("last_name" => "testsurename")
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
$array = array("first_name"=>"test","last_name"=>"testsurename");
$newarray = array();
foreach($array as $key=> $val)
{
    $newarray[][$key] = $val;
}
print_r($newarray);
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
$array = array(
    "0" => array("first_name" => "test"),
    "1" => array("last_name" => "testsurename")
);
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/f2ORH)**

Comment: Could also use `$newarray[] = array($key => $val);`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `array_walk`, but basically it's all the same.

```
$array = array("first_name"=>"test","last_name"=>"testsurename");

$result = array();

array_walk($array, 
           function(&$item, $key, $target) { $target[] = array($key => $item); },
           &$result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
<?php
$array = array("first_name"=>"test","last_name"=>"testsurename");

$final_array = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    array_push($final_array, [$key => $value]);
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [first_name] => test ) [1] => Array ( [last_name] => testsurename ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$inputArray = [
    "first_name" => "test",
    "last_name" => "testsurename"
];

$outputArray = array_reduce(array_keys($inputArray), function($carry, $key) use ($inputArray) {
   $carry[][$key] = $array[$key];
   return $carry;
}, []);

/**
result will be for $outputArray 
[
    ["first_name" => "test"],
    ["last_name" => "testsurename"]
];
**/
```